# MySQL error after rebooting (LAMPP)

Tags: mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I don't know if this is the right place to put this question.
I installed Lampp and followed this instructions http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#377 
and everything worked fine until i rebooted the computer and this happened

[image: MySQL error]

It can be because of i rebooted the computer while lampp was on.

Anyone that can help?

EDIT:

I can run php files. It's just phpmyadmin that doesn't work

And i get this in http://localhost/xampp/

[image]

Maybe this has something to do with it.

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another FTP daemon is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
Stopping XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: XAMPP-Apache is not running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-MySQL is not running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is not running.
XAMPP stopped.
```

Comment: What happens if you enter `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` at the command line and retry?

Comment: sudo: /etc/init.d/mysqld: command not found

Comment: Does `/opt/lampp/lampp` exist? Can you enter `/opt/lampp/lampp start` and retry?

Comment: In the windows client there is a button / menu in the xampp admin to start components at XAMPP startup. Not sure where to find it here.

Comment: `/opt/lampp/lampp startmysql` from the command line, but you should be able to configure it as a defualt. You can also choose to add a second line to the rc.local script as below, but I think that looks messy.

Comment: Check if there are any mysql processes running: `ps -ef | grep -i mysql`

Comment: `jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ ps -ef | grep -i mysql
mysql     1327     1  0 07:42 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/mysqld
jeggy    15040 14803  0 09:58 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i mysql`

Comment: Slightly off topic - but I find the easiest way to get a LAMP stack installed is to sudo tasksel and choose the LAMP option (do not deselect any other options which are ticked!). Note that tasksel may not be installed by default, in which case sudo apt-get install tasksel first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

The problem is another mysql daemon is running.

You might also need to stop the systems apache service too.
[`/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`]

Answer (score 0):

Add `/opt/lampp/lampp start` to `/etc/rc.local`, after the comments and but before the exit 0.

Comment: Bad advice as your webserver (part of LAMPP) obviously does start, otherwise you couldn't have a screenshot like that.

Answer (score 0):

got this same error due to my dumbness.. not rebooting but reinstalling without stopping the service(s) first I think... kinda new to running this locally... setup passwords then couldn't access localhost.. so I tried to reinstall.

the stopping servers in init.d advice doesn't work.

sudo: /etc/init.d/mysql: command not found (for example)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same problem.
Even if I had (supposedly) correctly uninstalled previous XAMPP and LAMPP installations, turns, that I had previous mysql server not simply installed, but also running. So I opened synaptics, found mysql, uninstalled, restarted XAMPP. 
Now its all good.